# Add stackexchange.com home button to the left of the "StackExchange" header menu

Tags: feature-request, homepage, header

If I want to quickly check the top related questions on the entire Stack Exchange network, and I'm in GIS or programmers or any specific site, I need to click the menu, then the Stack Exchange link, which is part of the about sentence:

[image: Stack Exchange link in dropdown]

That link seems almost like a hack to get back home.

I would suggest a home icon you can click, which would take you back to the [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) homepage. It could be the same size as the chat bubble icon used in the Stack Exchange menu, but just with a border and onhover effects.

I'm still fairly new at SE, so forgive me if this feature request wasn't well written (also please provide feedback if I infringed in any serious way).

EDIT:
I take back my earlier suggestion of using a home icon. I realize that would be inaccurate, because (as pointed out by Cody) each site is meant to be it's own and home should go to the individual sites homepage. 
I still think the button would hold great value, but I have no idea what it would look like... perhaps a globe or something. I just believe it would be convenient to have a one-click way to get back to a global view of all the most popular posts for the networks I view.

Comment: StackExchange.com is not exactly "home". The individual site that you're browsing is "home"; you get to that by clicking its logo. The fact that the sites are all run by the same network/organization isn't really important. The emphasis is strongly on the fact that each site is individual and self-contained.

Comment: EDIT: 
I take back my earlier suggestion of using a home icon. I realize that would be inaccurate, because (as pointed out by Cody) each site is meant to be it's own and home should go to the individual sites homepage.
I still think the button would hold great value, but I have no idea what it would look like... perhaps a globe or something.
I just believe it would be convenient to have a one-click way to get back to a global view of all the most popular posts for the networks I view.

(p.s. I couldn't edit my own post, because it has an image in it and I don't have enough rep to post images)

Comment: If your primary goal in visiting StackExchange.com is viewing the popular questions across the network, then shouldn't the MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ (also known as the Stack Exchange button) be enough? Or even *exactly* what you're looking for?

Comment: It's not bad, however it doesn't replace the stack exchange home.

Answer (score 6):

The questions shown on the homepage of [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) are *in* the dropdown menu, no need to actually navigate to another page.  Check it out:

[image: 1]

Only minor info (tags, times, summaries, and usernames) are missing from the full version:

[image: 2]

Comment: I didn't realize it was the same list, thanks for the tip.
Still, I would rather read that list in a larger expanded view with the features you mentioned.