# Question asked by low rep user. Another user added images. OP can't edit

Tags: feature-request, questions, new-users, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to edit my own question that has been edited by another user who included a picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103567/unable-to-edit-my-own-question-that-has-been-edited-by-another-user-who-included)

See this question: [UML Class Diagram for an E-commerce webSite?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9107448/561731)

(At the writing of this question the OP has 11 rep, so **now** he can add images, but he couldn't before he got to 10 rep)

If you look at the question's edits, the OP had two links to the UML diagrams originally, then another user turned them into images because he had the rights.

**BUT** then the OP wanted to make an update to his question, he couldn't due to the images!

What?

So as a new user he did as any sensible person would do. He thought of a solution and posted a **new** answer with his update.

Then an admin admonished him for doing that and updated the post accordingly, deleting the comments.

**Why** did this need to be done?

Why can't the OP edit his/her question when the images were added by another user?

Can we change it so that **if** another user adds images to an OPs post, any edit is **allowed** to have those images (and not any new ones)?

Thanks

---

Comments on the question (just in case they get removed):

[image]

Comment: Well my upvote puts him at 16 now - is that enough to let him edit?  This is such an edge case I doubt Jeff'll invest the time to fix it (I certainly wouldn't).

Comment: Poor liligago...

Comment: @AdamRackis the privilege is unlocked at 10. so he has it now, but did not have it when he posted those comments.

Comment: +1 for handdrawn circles! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta

Comment: This does seem like a pretty big flaw... on the other hand, the restriction has been in place for a while, and this is the first time I've ever heard of it coming up in practice. EDIT: oh, good close, @random!

Comment: it's kind of irrelevant since the question is off-topic and inappropriate for the site anyway. GIGO

Comment: @JeffAtwood I realize that, and I was one to vote to close on that SO question, I just thought the editing issue was a bit funky.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that needs to be fixed. I could easily see a high-rep user griefing a new user with this. Especially if they don't ask a decent question.

Comment: While this is certainly possible, I don't think we've had any serious cases in this line.