# Update Reputation FAQ - Posting Images

Tags: discussion, faq-update-request

This is pretty minor, but can we update the [reputation faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) to state that 10 rep is required to post an image in a question (and answer, I assume)?

I tried looking up the rep requirement for this privileged after reading [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121106/question-asked-by-low-rep-user-another-user-added-images-op-cant-edit#comment320674_121106) but it's not listed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reputation section of the faq lists the basics.

This section links you to [additional privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges) which includes [removing new users restrictions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user).

The FAQ is not meant to be a full reference.  The privilege page contains more details where we separate things out by privilege so that we can be more detailed.